# How to get data from text area and show it like news feed as messages

Tags: php

This is my form area where I am using text field or text area for status messages I want to get text from text area and want to print them.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" id="status-update-form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="2" name="status" id="status" placeholder="Anything special to share?"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-lg" style="padding: 13.4px;">Post</button>
        </div>
```

Comment: where is your php code? and where do you store the text? or its a one-time show text?

Comment: Improve formating

Answer (score 0):

You can access array $_POST after sending the form, e.g. $_POST['status']

```
<?php
if($_POST)
{
   print_r($_POST);
}
?>

<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="" id="status-update-form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="2" name="status" id="status" placeholder="Anything special to share?"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success  btn-block btn-lg" style="padding: 13.4px;">Post</button>
        </div>
</form>
```